# failed to create kind cluster on wsl2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kind

I have set up wsl2 with docker. Docker is running and `docker run hello-world` and `docker ps` work fine.
I want now to create a kind cluster. I am executing running the following command `kind create cluster`, but the following error comes up during step **Starting Control Plane**:

```
ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to init node with kubeadm: command "docker exec --privileged kind-control-plane kubeadm init --skip-phases=preflight --config=/kind/kubeadm.conf --skip-token-print --v=6" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: I0424 12:50:20.589544     134 initconfiguration.go:254] loading configuration from "/kind/kubeadm.conf"
```

Then there are many failed http requests to the API server and then this follows:

```
Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
        - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:108
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:259
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:112
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
error execution phase wait-control-plane
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:260
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:112
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594`
```

I have tried to set up my wsl2 again, or delete and reinstall kind and docker. But the same error came up.